# How can I convert this SQL query to a Django ORM statement?

Tags: mysql, django, django-models, orm

I have 3 models:

```
#Appointment
class Appointment(models.Model):
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(
        Doctor,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='doctor_appointment')
    patient = models.ForeignKey(
        Patient,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='patient_appointment')
    scheduled = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

# Doctor
class Doctor(models.Model):
    user_id = models.TextField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)

# Patients
class Patient(models.Model):
    user_id = models.TextField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
```

And I want to execute the below query using `Django ORM`:

```
SELECT 
d.first_name,
d.last_name,
d.specialty,
d.address,
a.scheduled

FROM appointment as a

LEFT JOIN patient as p ON p.id=a.patient_id

LEFT JOIN doctor as d ON d.id = a.doctor_id

WHERE p.user_id  = '12345';
```

I've come up with this statement:

```
ret = Appointment.objects.filter(patient__user_id='12345').values_list('doctor__first_name', 'doctor__last_name', 'scheduled')
```

but upon examining its raw query (`ret.query`) I can see that this is translated to a set of `INNER JOINS`.

Is there a way to get the query I want?

Comment: With the data you have shown, it surely shouldn't make any difference, because you don't allow null values on the doctor or patient foreign keys so there will always be a value.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman for your prompt reply! Would you mind telling me what would be the correct way to write my SQL statement, had null values on FK been allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid thinking in terms of SQL queries; the point of the ORM is that it is *object* based.

For the same reason, avoid things like `values_list` unless you really know you need a list. You should be asking for Appointment objects and their related Doctor and Patient objects.

What you really need to do is just to filter on Appointments and use `select_related` to query the related models. Django will then do the right thing, using INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN depending on whether null values are permitted.

So, for example:

```
Appointment.objects.filter(patient__user_id='12345').select_related('patient', 'doctor')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Just a minor remark from my side; in order to select the specific columns I needed I had to add `.values('doctor__first_name', 'doctor__last_name')` in the end

Comment: another thing (in case you know). How do I go about serializing the content of this custom query-set? I have serializers for each of my DB tables but I guess I might write a new one?